# Centering text in default beamer slides

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment

I want to redefine the frame template so that text is centered whenever I create a new frame, without using \centering in the frame environment.

This is what I am currently doing:

```
\begin{frame}\centering
Whatever is on slide
\end frame
```

I want to get rid of the \centering globally.

Answer (score 3):

Unlike [@samcarter’s answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/450409/164314) which uses `\AtBeginDocument`, my solution appends `\centering` immediately after the beginning of each frame and therefore limits its influence within the frames.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\apptocmd\beamer@framenotesbegin
  {\centering}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Whatever outside the frame is not affected

\begin{frame}
Whatever inside the frame is centered
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: frame notes centered]

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\AtBeginDocument{\centering}

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}
Whatever is on slide
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```